# Can indesign be asked to warn you if a picture is below a certain dpi?

Tags: adobe-indesign, ppi

Indesign has got a very good mechanism of spotting and warning broken links. Is there a mechanism where InDesign can automatically light up pics that are below a certain range of dpi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.... You can set up error warnings, but nothing will present the "application stopping" alert warning similar to missing links.

You could manually select each image and then use either the `Info` or `Links` Panel to check each linked image's PPI.

You can also use the **Preflight** panel in InDesign. (Window > Output > Preflight)

You have to set up a Profile for Preflight (Using the panel menu `Define Profiles`)...

[image]

[image]

There you can set conditions which will create an "error".

Once it's configured, you just need to watch the Preflight Panel. If there's a problem, it'll be listed there...

[image]

For print, you can also export to PDF and then run the Preflight tools in Acrobat to verify the PDF meets the standards desired. But that's external and not really part of InDesign directly.

But ultimately, there's nothing that is application-pausing with front most alert *forcing* you to click cancel or OK before moving on the same way missing/broken images present an alert.

Comment: Isnt prefilight absolutely that option, so wouldnt tha answer be yes?

Comment: @joojaa it presents warnings, but not the same way a missing image link does. A missing image halts the application until the user acknowledges the warning. Preflight only presents warning when you look for them. Even if there's a preflight warning, you can generate a PDF without ever seeing it. If there's a missing link, InDesign stops and **forces** the user to interact with the warning. So while the *intent* is the same, actual implementation by Adobe is vastly different.

Comment: It's really the first two paragraphs that don't really make sense. Your answer is basically: "Indesign doesn't have a mechanism to alert you about ppi.... Here's the indesign mechanism that alerts you about ppi". If you want to keep those 2 paragraphs, you may want to specify the type of alert you are talking about.